# Prettifying forms - what is the best we can use as a theming for pure civi forms?

Tags: contribution-page, theme

There's Shoreditch ext - bit seems it is only limited to backend admin UI?

Are there any other alternatives for contribution and event registration pages?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative could be the Haystack theme (although I have not tried what it does to event or contribution pages): https://github.com/mattwire/civicrm-haystacktheme